# createImageData vs. createImageDataHD

Tags: html5-canvas

What's the difference between createImageData and createImageDataHD? [The official specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#pixel-manipulation) for the non-HD version reads:

> Returns an ImageData object **with the given dimensions**. All the pixels in the returned object are transparent black.

And for the HD version:

> Returns an ImageData object **whose dimensions equal the dimensions given in the arguments, multiplied by the number of pixels in the canvas bitmap that correspond to each coordinate space unit.** All the pixels in the returned object are transparent black.

Can you explain to me what they mean with that and what's the use-case for the HD version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use-case is for higher resolution screens like Retina displays.

While such displays have more literal pixels, a browser being displayed on such a system still behaves as though it had a normal resolution thanks to the variability of CSS pixels; see [CSS's discussion of pixels and anchor units here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#length-units).

> For lower-resolution devices, and devices with unusual viewing distances, it is recommended instead that the anchor unit be the pixel unit. For such devices it is recommended that the pixel unit refer to the whole number of device pixels that best approximates the reference pixel.  [***I.e., let pixels be pixels on normal devices.***]
>
> For print media and similar high-resolution devices, the anchor unit should be one of the standard physical units (inches, centimeters, etc).   [***I.e., assume pixels are 96 dpi on high resolution devices.***]

This is important so that the doubled density of display pixels on a retina screen does not lead to every website being half as wide and half as high.

The [pixel manipulation routines](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#pixel-manipulation) of the canvas specification assume that one CSS pixel equals one pixel in the underlying bitmap, but this fails to take advantage of higher resolution screens.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let me check if I understood this correctly: When I have a canvas displayed on a retina display, and I do normal drawing operations on it, one logical pixel is actually rendered by 4 physical pixels. When I use getImageData, I get the approximated color value of 4 physical pixels as one logical pixel. But when I use getImageDataHD I get the color values of the actual physical pixels. Is that correct? Do I also understand correctly that on a normal desktop computer, there is no difference between the two functions?

Comment: I believe that both of those would be correct **in a browser that implements what the WHATWG describes**.  I do not know which browsers, if any, actually support the `HD` canvas context methods.